# How to export VARCHAR2 data that includes commas(!) to Excel from MSSQLMgmtStudio(2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export-to-excel

First, a grumble: MS builds SQL Server Studio AND Excel, but can't make one save in the standard format of the other?

OK, I'm a data analyst, but not allowed to change/mod either the data or structures directly. So full READ, but no WRITE.

I'm trying to do a dump so I can do some of this analysis offline, as I have no remote access either.

So one VARCHAR2 column in this table is for comments on the purchase of the asset being described/tracked. Of course, there are commas. The only export types built into SQL Server Studio are .csv and .txt, and .csv just turns into a mess when 'comma' is included as a delimiter.

So after an hour or so of screwing around with this, (including reading a thread on methods for excluding the one column from a SELECT while still exporting the other 221 columns in the table, without having to write them all out manually (fun reading, impressive, but means I'd have to figure out which of them actually works, and then still export the one column separately and insert it in the Excel separately)) I am throwing this problem on the pile at StackOverflow.

Someone else must have worked around this frustration of the .csv format as export VS the commas embedded in 'comment' text. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the SSMS Export Wizard? That's usually how I workaround that problem.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to write a .NET program to pull some data from SQL Server and then use a library to generate a CSV file that respects all the rules. Or even to use a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate an actual XLSX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply select all data in ssms result window, then copy and then paste in a blank excel file?
It should copy paste all data in correct format including comma valued fields in single column.

Try that.

Comment: And if you really got too much of data, using subset of data or a machine with bigger memory and 64bit office is recommended

Comment: After 'Save Results As...' didn't work, I tried this. Same result, but it give column headers too.

Comment: don't use save as option. Simply STEP1:select all  -  STEP2:copy - STEP3:paste in Excel

Comment: Thanks. This worked, and demonstrated that the issue was not entirely the commas. Following this method, the commas within columns ARE handled correctly, which then exposed the final issue. They've been cut-n-pasting Word text, including CRs, which this doesn't handle. Now the issue will be better user training.

Comment: great. then may be you can mark this as an answer. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

So If you replace the ' to some special character you can export it.

```
Select 
    Replace(columnName,'''','`') 
from Table
```

Other solution if you use the manager studio 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Comment: All my access is through 'linked servers', so I can't "connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine" to get at the SSMS import/export wizard from SSMS. 
There  is a copy of DTSWizard.exe installed, but I get a registration error. Ah, security. I'll see if I can get this to work. May be that I can't without direct access to the database, instead of through that 'link' set-up.